# How to turn on syntax highlighting in VIM 7.3 OSX

Tags: vim

System = OSX 10.9.4

I am trying to turn on syntax highlighting in vim while using the terminal. However, I am unable to get it to work properly.

Things I've tried:

- located the vimrc file and added the following code:

  ```
   set ai                  " auto indenting 
   set history=100         " keep 100 lines of history
   set ruler               " show the cursor position
   syntax on               " syntax highlighting
   set hlsearch            " highlight the last searched term
   filetype plugin on      " use the file type plugins
  ```
- Located vimrc under directory:

  ```
   cd /usr/share/vim/
  ```

The interesting thing is that once I add the code to the vimrc using vim, followed by exiting (x), and re-opening the file again, syntax is correctly highlighted in the vimrc.

However, when I try to make a new vim file called "test", copy the same code, save and exit. Re-open it, the syntax is not highlighted at all.

It appears that syntax highlighting only works when I open the actually vimrc file---and not when I try to create a new one or open another file that should have syntax highlighting.

- I've also tried to create a .vimrc (exact copy) under the ~/ (directory). No success.
- Made a new file called "test" and tried turning it on while active as well:

  ```
     vim test
  ```

"then within vim"

```
       :syntax on
```

I am really confused as to why this partially works.

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers!

p.s. I have followed these instructions as well from: http://geekology.co.za/article/2009/03/how-to-enable-syntax-highlighting-and-other-options-in-vim

*I am aware of macvim, but would like a solution for the native vim in terminal. Thanks.

Comment: Put `syntax on` in your vimrc. you shouldn't need to set it manually. Don't change anything in `/usr/share/vim/`. Also there won't be any syntax highlighting for files with no filetype. Try a `c` file or something or manually set the filetype `set ft=c`. You might also want a colorscheme.

Comment: Good article here:  http://www.vaughnemiller.com/2014/01/03/enabling-syntax-highlighting-for-vim-in-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. NEVER do anything in `$VIM` as it will work only by luck, cause unexpected behaviors and likely be overwritten next time Vim is updated.

   What you have put in `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` should be in `~/.vimrc`.
2. `filetype on` and `syntax on` are the bare minimum you need in your `~/.vimrc` for syntax highlighting to work.
3. `$ vim ~/.vimrc` gives you syntax highlighting because the file is recognized by Vim as a vim file. Filetype detection is mostly dependent on file extensions so you *can't* expect any syntax highlighting in a file called `test`.

   `$ vim test.py`, on the other hand, should give you syntax highlighting.

   If the filetype is not detected, you can force it with `:set filetype=python`.

Comment: The file extension was the issue. That was a terrible *noob mistake on my behalf. . Also, just fyi-there was no need to create a separate .vimrc under the home directory. The changes that were made under ~/user/share/vim/vimrc seemed to work fine. Granted, it is highly recommended to make a separate one just in case in the home directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

You most probably want to enable indentation along with syntax highlighting, so add these to lines to ~/.vimrc

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

Steps with screenshots can be found here
http://osxandiosdaily.com/how-to-enable-vim-syntax-highlighting-on-mac-osx/

Answer (score 6):

Inside of your file, enter command mode and enter the command

```
:syntax on
```